# Regular expression Extractor/json path Extractor in JMeter 3.2

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-3.2

I am getting response in JSON format as

```
"pushEndpoint": "https://update.kai.jiophone.net:8443/wpush/v1/gAAAAABZib4oJsO-pWBMxFb3_INBlTxSwfTBSh7aPA8O4he_a_Rr5Vbl6_SP0-Ceo4acKmkx-nHDCy2tSXEeo0k2zM6PBZAxb1jSdKXxt31lCcKuJOxhq5iiCoujT1Mq0959ToMMT73M"
```

I want to extract the value

```
/wpush/v1/gAAAAABZib4oJsO-pWBMxFb3_INBlTxSwfTBSh7aPA8O4he_a_Rr5Vbl6_SP0-Ceo4acKmkx-nHDCy2tSXEeo0k2zM6PBZAxb1jSdKXxt31lCcKuJOxhq5iiCoujT1Mq0959ToMMT73M
```

so that I can use this as variable in next request in JMeter 3.2.

I tried with regular expression in JMeter but no luck.

Comment: Be more specific.  What have you already tried?  Why approach did you use?  Why do you think it didn't work?  Don't worry about jmeter, be specific about what results you "wrongly" got from your own attempts.  Which regular expression?  How did you invoke it?  Don't worry about "Please help" etc - try to reword your question so that it might be helpful to someone else in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Regular Expression Extractor` to get from / character until " character:

```
Reference Name: myVariable

Regular Expression: 8443/([^"]+)"

Template $1$

Match No. 1
```

Comment: Hello I have used as same as mentioned above it did not work.

Comment: Regular Expression Extractor is added under the relevant HTTP request? Do you get any value to myVariable?

Comment: Using regular expression given by you i am getting default value.